# How to verify dropdownlist values are selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, drop-down-menu

My ASP.NET application has a requirement, where if a user selects a country from a country dropdownlist and if a country has a state (which usually every country has!), then a validation needs to be written down that checks that the state is selected.

If no state exists (for selected country, from country dropdownlist) then the validation should skipped and no error/validation message should thrown up.

I need to validate the state selection on the click of the button

Please guide me!

**Code**

```
   private void LoadCountry()
    {
        Country objcountry= new Country ();
        int iSuccess = 0;
        DataSet dsCtry= new DataSet();
        dsCtry= objcountry.LoadCountry();
        if (iSuccess == 0)
        {

            ddlCtry.DataSource = dsCtry.Tables[0];
            ddlCtry.DataTextField = "COUNTRY";
            ddlCtry.DataValueField = "COUNTRY";
            ddlCtry.DataBind();
            ddlCtry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select --", ""));
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you filling up the dependent dropdowns, coz you can enable and disable required field validators

Comment: Using Dataset.tables[0] as datasource to country dropdownlist(and same for state dropdownlist)

Comment: Ain't you filtering it for the country, are you posting back after country selection, show some code

Comment: Is the state selected from a drop down list that is populated when the country is selected or is it entered in a text box?

Comment: first option: populated when country is selected

Comment: P.S.: I need to validate state selection on the click of the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use two dropdownlists

The first one is for countries. The second is for states of country.

When user select one county, you get states of that country and bind into the second dropdownlist. And base on the size of the second dropdownlist, you can validate the selected state.

Hope this helps ^^

Comment: You have stated the logic, which is right. but how to validate that state has been selected by user? you mention "based on size"?

Comment: When you get states for the selected country and bind it into the second dropdownlist. If that country has no state, it means the dropdownlist contains no item. You can use `DropDownListID.Items.Count == 0` for server-side or `dropdownlistID.options.length == 0` for client-side validation. Or if you add something like `Please Select State` if that country contains states. Then you check the items size `== 0` for the country with state, and `DropDownListID.SelectedIndex != 0` or `dropdownlistID.options.selectedIndex != 0` when that country has states ^^

Comment: I am validating when the Submit button is clicked. Items.count would just count the number of rows.What if the user selects "--Select--" option? The count is one but that is not correct choice.. you got it?

Comment: if you add `--Select--` option, then if `count == 1` then you don't have to validate anything. if `count > 1` then you have to check `DropDownListID.SelectedIndex != 0` or `dropdownlistID.options.selectedIndex != 0`

Answer (score 1):

write a javascript function

```
            if (document.getElementById('ddlcountry').value == '--Select--' || document.getElementById('ddlcountry').value == '0')
            {   
                 alert("Please select a Country");
                document.getElementById('ddlcountry').focus();
                return false;
            } 
           else
           {
            if (document.getElementById('ddlstate').value == '--Select--' || document.getElementById('ddlstate').value == '0')
            {   
                 alert("Please select a State");
                document.getElementById('ddlstate').focus();
                return false;
            } 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. When the country drop down list selected index change you check if the state drop down list contain items and if contain enable the validator and if there is no item disable the required field validator.
2. To make the validation client side using jquery.